# Spring MVC: Recommended way to validate things that require existing Services/Repositories

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

Spring MVC offers form validation through both annotations on the forms (for example @NotNull) to do a simple check of the value of a field, and custom Validators, which help you do cross-field validations (verifying two password fields contain the same value, etc).

I am looking for the recommended way to do validations that go a bit further, however. For example verify if a username is not used already, which requires a call to the database. I assume I can simply inject my PersonRepository into the custom validator (which is an @Component) after all, but I doubt it'll be transactionally safe..or very clean.

What is the recommended way to do this, that requires the least amount of duplicated code? Or should I simply write my own validation layer, that throws some ValidationException with a list of validationmessages, which I have to map to the bindingresult?

Answer (score 2):

To just clearify: Spring MVC don't offers form validation by itself. It integrates with Java Bean validation vendors (like Hibernate Validator).

You're right: If you configure `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` as a bean in your application context, you benefit from dependency management in your custom validators. In my opinion there is no need to implement a custom validation layer within your setup, since you already have a powerful and generic abstraction of validation which even conforms to Java standards.

If you worry about whether calling your repository in validator is transaction safe or not see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions for details. CRUD operations are transactional by default. If you need a more sophisticated validation logic with needs a transaction context, you could either make your `isValid(...)` method transactional by annotating it, or you could autowire a business service with likely is transactional by itself. This perfectly integrate with the concepts of Spring.

**Use the same business transaction**

If you need to handle validation and business logic (check whether a user name is already used and insert a new if not) in the same transaction you could think about restricting those validations in Controller layer to the basic ones (`@NotNull` for example). This will ensure, that only syntactic correct requests make their way to your service layer.

In the service you will use an autowired validator and trigger the entire validation constraints manually. If you have a combination Hibernate as JPA vendor and Hibernate as Validation vendor you could even make use of the integration of both (pre persit and pre update events) which will cause the validation to occur automatically before the changes are written to the database.

However you decide, you will likely use validation groups to split the constraints into two groups 'syntactic' and 'semantic' for example. If you call the validator manually you can pass the groups you want to take into account. If you use integrated validation with Hibernate you can control the groups for the different events by specifying the following properties:

- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist
- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update

If you decide for this way you will simply call your transactional business service method from your controller. Business logic and validation will participate in the same transaction this way.

Comment: I might not have been entirely clear. I want the validation to be in the same transaction as the business processing that should happen afterwards (For example, verifying Person name does not exist, then INSERTing a new Person with that name later on). If I do the SELECT call (to check the name is used already) before the Service gets called later on, we're talking about two separate transactions, it seems to me :-)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I don't exactly see how you'd map your exceptions to the correct "keys" in your bindingResult, though. I'll probably just end up throwing an ValidationException(key, message), and use some kind of template in my controllers to catch them, and tie them to the bindingResult (as either a general error, or a specific one).